# I got Bad Request (400) when tryin to login to djngo website

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-authentication

I have Django website hosted to **DigitalOcean** , i'm using **postgres db , nginx , gunicorn and ubuntu 18.04**. I'm using django authentication system, i created normal user, but i could logged in successfully only few times after creating the new account after that i got **Bad Request (400)**  , and the admin was running with css style but now only html in rendered , but the style in other pages that users can visit are working fine with style. the two problems appears in the same time.

when i turn debug to true i got :

**SuspiciousFileOperation at /fr/account/login/**

Storage can not find an available filename for "users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/no__QKvIRQ8_2N3XJKL.png". Please make sure that the corresponding file field allows sufficient "max_length".

This is my nginx configuration
Please help me
**Thanks in advance**

```
server {
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }
    
     location /media/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
        image_filter_buffer 10M;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server_domain_or_IP/fullchain.pem; # managed $
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server_domain_or_IP/privkey.pem; # manage$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}  
server {
    if ($host = server_domain_or_IP) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = server_domain_or_IP) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    client_max_body_size 100M;


}
```

Comment: Can you try to enable debug in Django settings and upload the stack trace for the request that returns 400?

Comment: i got this when debug is true:                                                        SuspiciousFileOperation at /fr/account/login/

Storage can not find an available filename for "users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/users/2020/07/03/no__QKvIRQ8_2N3XJKL.png". Please make sure that the corresponding file field allows sufficient "max_length".

Comment: It seems that django cannot generate a valid path for the image you are trying to save (it fails here https://github.com/django/django/blob/17752003a8c115ff79f5f21655f5e9b8b2af67f4/django/core/files/storage.py#L93 ) . But why are you saving an image during login? Another strange thing is the filename with the string "users/2020/07/03/" repeated many times.

Comment: This is my model field where i save profile image,

Comment: This is my model field where i save profile image, `photo = models.ImageField(_('photo'), default='no_image.png', upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True)` i don't know why **users/2020/07/03/** is repeated many times, and i'm saving profile images during registration